# Continue processing Loop using Data Flow pipeline

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

I am playing around with Data Flows and trying to learn how to use them.  I have found plenty of examples showing how to use the different blocks but none of them really explain how to handle exceptions.

My main question is how to continue a foreach loop if an exception occurs or the output of a previous transform block is not what you are expecting.  Below is a simple Windows forms application I am using to test with.  Its just a single button that loops through a list of numbers and displays them.

I've added an if statement to the action block that says if the number=5, throw an exception.  The loop looks like it keeps processing after it hit the exception but it stops writing the output after it hits the exception.  The exception also never goes to the catch clause in the foreach loop.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataFlowsTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<int> TestList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

            var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(item =>
            {
                if (item == 5)
                    throw new Exception("Blech.");
                Debug.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            });


            foreach(var number in TestList)
            {
                try
                {
                    actionBlock.Post(number);
                }
                catch(AggregateException ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            actionBlock.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

This code returns
1
2
3
4
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in DataFlowsTest.exe
An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in DataFlowsTest.exe but was not handled in user code
Blech.

Comment: please stop changing the type of exceptions I'm trying to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I implemented it. I can share a lot more on Github if this approach interests you. I use dataflow quite a lot so I have implemented a whole lot of other IDataFlow classes based on this approach.

## The building block

Essentially, by wrapping every message in a class called a `Flow<T>`, we can implement a [Railway Oriented](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/) approach. A flow has two states: Failure or Success. Successful flows are `Flow<T>`'s are passed to the next custom dataflow or connected to a `FailureBlock : ITargetBlock<IFlow>` on failure. (essentially an `ActionBlock<IFlow>` which deals with exceptions, logs etc.

My basic Flow class looks as follows:

```
public class Flow<T> : IFlow
{
  public T Value { get; private set; }
  public Exception Exception { get; private set; }
  public bool Success => Exception is null;
  public bool Failure => !Success;
  public void Fail(Exception exception) => Exception = exception;
  public Flow(T value) => Data = value;
  public Flow(Exception exception) => Fail(exception);
  public static Flow<T> FromValue<T>(T data) => new Flow<T>(data);
}
```

```
public interface IFlow
{
  bool Success { get; }
  bool Failure { get; }
  Exception Exception { get; }
  void Fail(Exception exception);
}
```

## The resulting custom IDataflow

The following part looks scary, but don't be. It's essentially a TransformBlock wrapper with two extra features:

enter code here1. each custom `FlowBlock<T1,T2>` wraps methods into a `try { } catch { }`

2. the `LinkTo` method links successful flows to the next block and failures to the `FailureBlock`

```
public class FlowBlock<TInput, TOutput>: IPropagatorBlock<Flow<TInput>, Flow<TOutput>>
{
    protected override ITargetBlock<Flow<TInput>> Target => TransformBlock;
    protected override ISourceBlock<Flow<TOutput>> Source => TransformBlock;
    private TransformBlock<Flow<TInput>, Flow<TOutput>> TransformBlock { get; }
    private FailureBlock FailureBlock { get; }
    public FlowBlock(
        Func<TInput, Task<TOutput>> transform,
        ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions dataflowBlockOptions,
        FailureBlock failureBlock)
    {
        TransformBlock = new TransformBlock<Flow<TInput>, Flow<TOutput>>(
            async inFlow =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return new Flow<TOutput>(await transform(inFlow.Data));
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    return new Flow<TOutput>(exception);
                }
            },
            dataflowBlockOptions);
    }
    public override IDisposable LinkTo(
        ITargetBlock<Flow<TOutput>> target,
        DataflowLinkOptions linkOptions)
        => new Disposable(
            Source.LinkTo(target, linkOptions, flow => flow.Success),
            Source.LinkTo(OutputBlock, linkOptions, flow => flow.Failure));
}
```

Let me know in the comments if you are interested and I'll gladly open a github repo with a whole lot more details.

Answer (score 1):

You're throwing an exception within your block. This will cause the block to move to a faulted state and attaches the exception to it's `Completion` task.

Your code only has `try/catch` around the `actionBlock.Post`, that's not where the exception is thrown.

Since the exception is attached to the completion task the only way to to catch the exception outside the block is to `await actionBlock.Completion`, that will re-throw the exception outside the block and allow you catch `(Exception ex)`.

To prevent the block from faulting; catch the exception within the block. If an exception leaves a block, the block will be faulted and no longer accept new inputs.

```
var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(item =>
{
    try
    {
        if (item == 5)
            throw new Exception("Blech.");
        Debug.WriteLine(item.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }

});
```

In addition you can also handle the result of `Post` or better yet `SendAsync` and react to the block fault:

```
foreach (var number in TestList)
{
    if(!actionBlock.Post(number))
        actionBlock.Complete();
    try
    {
        await actionBlock.Completion;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        //actionBlock is now dead
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  My understanding was that exceptions would bubble up, which if I am understanding you correctly, they will just not he way I have implemented it.

Comment: Corrrect, exceptions thrown from a block will be attached to the blocks completion task. If you've linked the blocks and propagate completion the exception will flow through your pipeline, moving each block to the faulted state and be attached to the final block's completion task where it can be re-thrown by awaiting it.

Answer (score 0):

You are throwing an `Exception` but only catching `AggregateException`

Add a catch for generic (`Exception ex`) or for the type you want to catch

Comment: changing the AggregateException to a generic Exception produces the same result.